# WPF Text Box allowing decimal entries

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, floating-point

I am new to WPF (VS2013, .NET Framework 4.5) and what was a big suprise to me is that I can not enter a float value to my text box.
My text box is bound to a float variable.  If that variable defaults to say 5, then text box will show 5.  But I have an issue:

I can not enter . if I want to have say 5.5.  To solve this, I found someone's suggestion to add to xaml for text box binding "`StringFormat=N2`".

That created even more issues:

```
1. Now even if I have even number like 5, it shows as 5.00

2. If I put cursor btw 2 zeros or anywhere else, neither backspace nor delete key will delete the entrie

3. If I put cursor btw 5 and . (in 5.00) and type ".10", I end up with 5.10.00.
```

Is it possible that number entry in WPF is so complicated???  All I want is to enter a number that will be stored in a float.

```
If I enter 5, it should show as 5 in TextBox.  

If I enter 5.05, than that is how it should show in TextBox.
```

The underlying float variable can hold both 5 and 5.05, both as a float.

UPDATE:
Here is my code

```
private float age;

public float Age {
    get { return age; }
    set
   {
        if (value <= 0 || value > 120)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The age must be between 0 and 120 years");
        }
        age= value;
    } 
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txtAge" Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N1, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
```

Comment: You should specify with version of framework you use.

Comment: @FabienBondi  Updated, very first line.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Standard Numeric Format Strings

> The number is converted to a string of the form "-d,ddd,ddd.ddd…",
>   where '-' indicates a negative number symbol if required, 'd'
>   indicates a digit (0-9), ',' indicates a thousand separator between
>   number groups, and '.' indicates a decimal point symbol.

It would seem that N will include thousands separators.

See also [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no **binding** in your code. Note the ***Path=Age*** :

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N1, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

The binding between the model view with the view model:

```
var myModel = new ViewModel();
control.DataContext = myModel;
```

Then the ViewModel (implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface)

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private float _age;

    public float Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_age)) return;
            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You should be interested in MVVM literature:

- [MVVM overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)
- [MVVM by Microsoft Patterns & Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

As the other answer suggests, you may have a mismatch between what you expect to be the decimal separator (.) and what your system consider as the decimal separator (maybe something else like ,).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this site, the trick is to force the behavior of framework 4

If you still want to use ‘UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged’, you can force the .NET 4 behavior in your .NET 4.5 application by adding the following line of code to the constructor of your App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences
          .KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
}
```

Source:

http://www.sebastianlux.net/2014/06/21/binding-float-values-to-a-net-4-5-wpf-textbox-using-updatesourcetriggerpropertychanged/